# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException al contar las consonantes de una cadena en Java

Tags: java, array

Estoy tratando de contar las consonantes en una cadena dada previamente. Para ello, le he hecho un split en caracteres. Luego he declarado una cadena con las consonantes y he hecho lo mismo.
Luego, con un for he recorrido el array y lo he comparado con el array de las consonantes en busca de coincidencias, pero me devuelve

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 22

Se que 22 son el número de consonantes, pero no se de qué manera puedo plantearlo para que no se salga del array y no me de error.

```
public class Contar_letras {
public static void main(String[] args){
    //declaramos string
    String str = "Estoy haciendo los ejercicios voluntarios de Programación I";
    //Le hacemos split en caracteres
    String[]totalchar = str.split("");
    //declaramos string de consonantes y lo separamos en caracteres
    String consonantes = "bcdfghjklmnñpqrstvwxyz";
    String[]charconso = consonantes.split("");
    //declaramos un contador para las consonantes
    int contadorconso = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i<totalchar.length;i++){
        if(totalchar[i].equalsIgnoreCase(charconso[i])){
            contadorconso++;
        }        
    }
```

Gracias

Comment: Te doy la bienvenida al sitio. Vas por el buen camino, pero tienes algún fallo de planteamiento en la búsqueda de consonantes. Tienes un único bucle que itera por todas las letras de la cadena de entrada, con la letra en la misma posición del array de consonantes. Es decir que comparas E con b, s con c, t con d, etc. Tendrías que comparar todas las letras de la cadena de entrada con todas las consononantes, es decir dos bucles aniedados, el segundo bucle llegaría hasta la longitud de consontantes, por lo que no te daria esa excepción. Si es posible usa charAt en lugar de split también.

Comment: Gracias, es exactamente eso.

Comment: Como te dice @ordago es correcto. Pero me pregunto no te sería más fácil comparar con las vocales y el espacio almacenados en un array pues con esto reducirías el número de iteraciones internas lo que lleva a un mejor desempeño. Por cierto revisa la respuesta de `el.trasgu` es una respuesta válida pero no usa el array de consonantes

Answer (score 0):

A ver que te parece:

```
public class ContarLetras {
public static void main(String[] args){
    //declaramos string a contar
    String str = "Estoy haciendo los ejercicios voluntarios de Programación I";
    //creamos un contador del Sstring
    int contador = str.length();
   
    //declaramos un contador para las vocales, los espacios y las consonantes
    int contadorV = 0;
    int contadorE = 0;
    int contadorC = 0;

    //hacemos el bucle
    for(int i = 0; i < strArr.length; i++){
        //si hay vocales (minúsculas o acentuadas)
        if ((str.charAt(i)=='a') || (str.charAt(i)=='e') || (str.charAt(i)=='i') || 
                (str.charAt(i)=='o') || (str.charAt(i)=='u') || (str.charAt(i)=='A') || 
                (str.charAt(i)=='E') || (str.charAt(i)=='I') || 
                (str.charAt(i)=='O') || (str.charAt(i)=='U') ||
                (str.charAt(i)=='á') || (str.charAt(i)=='é') || (str.charAt(i)=='í') || 
                (str.charAt(i)=='ó') || (str.charAt(i)=='ú') || (str.charAt(i)=='Á') || 
                (str.charAt(i)=='É') || (str.charAt(i)=='Í') || 
                (str.charAt(i)=='Ó') || (str.charAt(i)=='Ú')){
            contadorV++;
        }
        //si hay espacios
        else if ((str.charAt(i)==' ')){
            contadorE++;
        }
        //si no coincide con vocales minúsculas, mayúsuclas o acentuadas y espacios
        else if ((str.charAt(i)!='a') || (str.charAt(i)!='e') || (str.charAt(i)!='i') || 
                (str.charAt(i)!='o') || (str.charAt(i)!='u') || (str.charAt(i)!='A') || 
                (str.charAt(i)!='E') || (str.charAt(i)!='I') || 
                (str.charAt(i)!='O') || (str.charAt(i)!='U') ||
                (str.charAt(i)!='á') || (str.charAt(i)!='é') || (str.charAt(i)!='í') || 
                (str.charAt(i)!='ó') || (str.charAt(i)!='ú') || (str.charAt(i)!='Á') || 
                (str.charAt(i)!='É') || (str.charAt(i)!='Í') || 
                (str.charAt(i)!='Ó') || (str.charAt(i)!='Ú') || (str.charAt(i)!=' ')){
            contadorC++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("La frase tiene un total de: " + contador + " caracteres");
    System.out.println("Hay un total de: " + contadorV + " vocales");
    System.out.println("Hay un total de: " + contadorE + " espacios");
    System.out.println("Las consonantes son: " + contadorC);
    System.out.println("La suma de las vocales, los espacios y las consonantes, es de: " + (contadorV + contadorE + contadorC) + " caracteres");
}
```

}

Comment: Cambia las comparaciones por `equals`. Para que la respuesta tenga el estándar de Java. Buena aproximación saludos 

Comment: Hola DavElsanto, he probado a usar equals, pero me da error. 

Me podrías explicar como se usaría con equals ?. 

Te refieres a sustituir str.charAt(i)=='o' por str.charAt(i).equal('o')